# What happens if multiple WillRepeatedly actions are specified on a google mock?

Tags: c++, googletest, googlemock

I have this kind of test setup:

```cpp
for (...)
{
    std::unique_ptr<MockObject> mock = std::make_unique<MockObject>();
    const SomeObject* validObject = ...;
    EXPECT_CALL(*mock, method(_)).WillRepeatedly(Return(validObject));
}
```

Is this guaranteed to return the `validObject` object local to the scope of the current `for`?
If so, would it behave the same if the mock was declared outside the `for`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this example, each iteration of the for loop makes a new `MockObject` `mock`.

The `EXPECT_CALL....WillRepeatedly` line will set the return value for this method *of that mock object only* to whatever `validObject` points to.

> would it behave the same if the mock was declared outside the for?

Yes, at least this part of the test will. The difference is that the `mock` object will be shared between all iterations of the for loop and will hold its state betewen iterations, I'd double check that the test doesn't assume that each iteration of the loop is getting a new mock object.

Comment: So the `WillRepeatedly` called on the second time will completely override the call happened the first time?

Comment: As long as both `WillRepeatedly` calls are on the same object, yes.